# GCP Helm Cloud Builder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-build

Just curious, why isn't there a helm cloud builder officially supported? It seems like a very common requirement, yet I'm not seeing one in the list here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders

I was previously using alpine/helm in my cloudbuild.yaml for my helm deployment as follows:

```
steps:
  # Build app image
  - name: gcr.io/cloud_builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - -t
      - $_IMAGE_REPO/$_CONTAINER_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - ./cloudbuild/$_CONTAINER_NAME/

  # Push my-app image to Google Cloud Registry
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - $_IMAGE_REPO/$_CONTAINER_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA

  # Configure a kubectl workspace for this project
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
    args:
      - cluster-info
    env:
      - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_REGION=$_CUSTOM_REGION
      - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=$_CUSTOM_CLUSTER
      - KUBECONFIG=/workspace/.kube/config

  # Deploy with Helm
  - name: alpine/helm
    args:
      - upgrade
      - -i
      - $_CONTAINER_NAME
      - ./cloudbuild/$_CONTAINER_NAME/k8s
      - --set
      - image.repository=$_IMAGE_REPO/$_CONTAINER_NAME,image.tag=$COMMIT_SHA
      - -f
      - ./cloudbuild/$_CONTAINER_NAME/k8s/values.yaml
    env:
      - KUBECONFIG=/workspace/.kube/config
      - TILLERLESS=false
      - TILLER_NAMESPACE=kube-system
      - USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
timeout: 1200s
substitutions:
  # substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  # dynamicSubstitutions: true
  _CUSTOM_REGION: us-east1
  _CUSTOM_CLUSTER: demo-gke
  _IMAGE_REPO: us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/fakeproject/my-docker-repo
  _CONTAINER_NAME: app2

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
  # In this option we are providing the worker pool name that we have created in the previous step
  workerPool:
    'projects/fakeproject/locations/us-east1/workerPools/cloud-build-pool'
```

And this was working with no issues. Then recently it just started failing with the following error so I'm guessing a change was made recently:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://10.10.2.2/version": getting credentials: exec: executable gke-gcloud-auth-plugin not found"
```

I get this error regularly on VM's and can workaround it by setting `USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True`, but that does not seem to fix the issue here if I add it to the `env` section. So I'm looking for recommendations on how to use helm with Cloud Build. alpine/helm was just something I randomly tried and was working for me up until now, but there's probably better solutions out there.

Thanks!